# Open path to local file in project on deployment

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any way to open source of deployment file which is same with local. For example: I have project - 'myProject' with 'libs' folder. It has default server configured in deployment options. There is the same 'libs' folder on server. I want to open path of this file in deployment source tree by clicking on local file. Is there any way to do it in phpStorm?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, as long as you have setup deployment correctly (it's working as it should).

**Navigate | Select In... | Remote Host** ( <kbd>Alt + F1, 3</kbd> using Default keymap)

Comment: Thank you! You're my saviour. I've been looking for this feature very long time!